# Enabling modal (Bootstrap version 3.3.6) through select option?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog, html-select, bootstrap-modal

**Example: When I select option "volvo", the modal appear.**
The modal not appear correctly.

```
<label>Recinto</label>
   <select class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cria-recinto">
      <option data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cria-recinto">O meu coliseu</option>
      <option>volvo</option>
      <option>A minha arena</option>
      <option>a garagem da minha vizinha</option>
      <option>Na esquina</option>
   </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
   $('select').change(function () {
   if ($(this).val() == "volvo") {
   $('#cria-recinto').modal('show');

}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

**HTML**

```
<label>Recinto</label>
<select class="form-control">
  <option>O meu coliseu</option>
  <option>volvo</option>
  <option>A minha arena</option>
  <option>a garagem da minha vizinha</option>
  <option>Na esquina</option>
</select>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Show what you want
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
  $('select').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "volvo") {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
  });

});
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/DTcHh/15913/)